# Consider an ellipse x^2/144 + y^2/64 = 1.A line is drawn tangent to the ellipse at a point P. A line segment drawn from the origin to a point Q on thi

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

Consider an ellipse $x^2/144 + y^2/64 = 1$. A line is drawn tangent to the ellipse at a point P. A line segment drawn from the origin to a point Q on thi

[image]

This is the question pic

Comment: Your question is likely to be closed for several reasons.  Most important of these is that you have not shown what you have tried and where you are stuck, making it difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation of the given ellipse is

$$ \dfrac{x^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{y^2}{b^2} = 1 $$

with $a = 12, b = 8$

The parametric equation of the ellipse is

$P = (x, y) = (a \cos t , b \sin t )$

The tangent vector at P is along the vector $V$,

$V = (- a \sin t, b \cos t )$

Therefore the equation of the tangent is

$q(t,s) = P + s V = (a \cos t , b \sin t ) + s (- a \sin t, b \cos t ) $

The minimum distance from the origin to $q(t)$ determines the point $Q$

$ q(t,s) \cdot q(t,s) = (P + s V) \cdot (P + s V) = P \cdot P + 2 P \cdot V + s^2 V \cdot V $

The minimum distance occurs at $ s_1 = - \dfrac{ P \cdot V}{ V \cdot V} $

This evaluates to:

$s_1 =  \dfrac{(a^2 - b^2) \sin t \cos t }{ a^2 \sin^2 t + b^2 \cos^2 t } $

Therefore, point Q is given by

$Q = P + s_1 V = ( a \cos t , b \sin t ) + \dfrac{(a^2 - b^2) \sin t \cos t }{ a^2 \sin^2 t + b^2 \cos^2 t } (- a \sin t, b \cos t ) $

The area of $\triangle POQ $ is given by

$\text{Area} = \frac{1}{2} s_1 | P, V | = \frac{1}{2} s_1 (ab) $

Thus the maximum area corresponds to maximum $s_1$, so we want to maximize (over $t$), the following function:

$s1 = f(t) =\dfrac{(a^2 - b^2) \sin t \cos t }{ a^2 \sin^2 t + b^2 \cos^2 t } $

Using the double angle formula, this reduces to,

$f(t) = (a^2 - b^2) \dfrac{ \sin 2 t }{ (a^2 + b^2) + (b^2 - a^2) \cos 2 t } $

The numerator of $f'(t) / (a^2 - b^2) $ is given by

$g(t) = 2 \cos 2 t ( (a^2 + b^2) + (b^2 - a^2) \cos 2 t ) + 2 (b^2 - a^2) \sin^2 2 t $

And this reduces to

$g(t) = 2 \cos 2 t (a^2 + b^2) + 2 (b^2 - a^2 ) = 0$

Hence the solution is

$ \cos 2 t =  \dfrac{a^2 - b^2}{a^2 + b^2} $

From which,

$ \sin 2 t = \sqrt{ 1 - \cos^2 2 t } = \dfrac{1}{a^2 + b^2} \sqrt{ (a^2 + b^2)^2 - (a^2 - b^2)^2}  = \dfrac{2 a b}{a^2 + b^2}$

Using this value of $2 t$ we can evaluate $f(t)$ :

$f(t) = (a^2 - b^2) \dfrac{ \sin 2 t }{ (a^2 + b^2) + (b^2 - a^2) \cos 2 t } $

Substitute $\cos 2 t $ and $\sin 2 t $, to get,

$f(t) = (a^2 - b^2) (2 ab) \dfrac{1}{ (a^2 + b^2)^2 - (a^2 - b^2)^2 }
       = \dfrac{(a^2 - b^2)}{2 a b} $

Therfore the maximum area is

$ \text{Area Max } = \frac{1}{4} (a^2 - b^2)$

With $a^2 = 144 , b^2 = 64 $, we get

$ \text{Area Max } = \frac{1}{4} (144 - 64) = 20$